# Creating multiple dataframes from 2 data frames basis dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, join

I am new to Python and would need some help with my problem:

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:
df1

```
date       col1 col2 col3
01-01-2008  nan 16  19
02-01-2008  nan 25  20
03-01-2008  nan nan nan
04-01-2008  18  18  nan
```

I have another dataframe that looks like:
df2

```
start        end         col4
01-01-2008  04-01-2008  [col1,col2]
02-01-2008  04-01-2008  [col1]
03-01-2008  04-01-2008  [col3]
```

I need to write a code such that I have values of col1 col2 from date 1-1-2008 to 4-1-2008 stored in one dataframe and values of col1 from 02-01-2008-04-01-2008 stored in another dataframe and so forth.

Basically I want my output something like this:
df3

```
date       col1 col2
01-01-2008  nan 16
02-01-2008  nan 25
03-01-2008  nan nan
04-01-2008  18  18
```

df4

```
date       col1
02-01-2008  nan
03-01-2008  nan
04-01-2008  18
```

df5

```
date        col3
03-01-2008  nan
04-01-2008  nan
```

Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if you face any problem. Here you go:

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
    start = df2["start"][i]
    end = df2["end"][i]
    cols = df2["col4"][i].replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",")
    print(df1.set_index("date",drop=True).loc[[df1[start:end]],cols])
```

Comment: Hey Thank you! I am getting a key error in the second line  start = df2["start"][i]

Comment: I tried using start=df2["start"].iloc[i] Now it gives an error in the 4th line cols = df2["col4"][i].replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",")

Comment: The error is AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: @PSharma Can you share the data ?